longitude is wrong while reading ERA5 data after using flex_extract and CDS api download ERA5,
I am trying to download ERA5 data via flex_extract v7.1.2. I used flex_extract v7.1.2 to download the global ERA5 data (GRIB2 format) for January 2023, but was unable to use the data to drive FLEXPART. Specific error information is as follows:
enter image description here
I checked my OUTGRID file and found that OUTGRID file was correct.
According to the Q&A ticket on the flexpart.eu website (#238 (Inconsistency when shifting longitudes?) – FLEXPART.EU), I checked the relevant parameter in gridcheck_ecmwf.f90. I found that the GRIB2 file I downloaded and converted through flex_extract outputs xaux1in (longtitude of first grid point in degrees) equals 181 and xaux2in (longtitude of last grid point in degrees) equals 180. The correct GRIB2 file should output xaux1in equals 182 and xaux2in equals 181. I don’t know what went wrong because I didn’t get any errors when downloading the data using flex_extract.
I really need your help, thank you!
